# Block a comma using regular expressions in multiline text

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a specific validation scenario that I am trying to solve using regexp pattern in JavaScript. I am struggling to write a suitable regular expression.

The rule is that validation must fail if a comma appears anywhere within a multiline piece of text that is enterred by the user into a text area, but ***only*** if it appears BEFORE a pipe character on the same line. It is assumed that every line will contain a pipe character somewhere (this is enforced elsewhere).

Examples below should clarify the requirement:

**Example 1 - PASS:** *No commas*

```
one|One
two|Two
three|Three
```

**Example 2 - PASS:**
*Comma appears, but after pipe character and so is ok*

```
one|One
two|Tw,o
three|Three
```

**Example 3 - FAIL:** *Comma appears before pipe character*

```
o,ne|One
two|Two
three|Three
```

**Example 4 - FAIL:** *Comma appears before pipe character*

```
one|One
two,|Two
three|Three
```

The closest attempt I have got so far is:

```
/^[^,]+$/g
```

However, this doesn't take into account that a comma after the pipe character is permitted.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223783/discussion-on-question-by-steve-griffiths-block-a-comma-using-regular-expression).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach could be using a negative lookahead to assert that the line does not contain a pipe after a comma.

```
^(?![^,\r\n]*,[^\r\n|]*\|).*(?:\r?\n(?![^,\r\n]*,[^\r\n|]*\|).*)*$
```

In parts

- `^` Start of the string
- `(?![^,\r\n]*,[^\r\n|]*\|)` Assert not a comma before a pipe char
- `.*` Match the whole line
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\r?\n` match a newline
  - `(?![^,\r\n]*,[^\r\n|]*\|)` Assert not a comma before a pipe char
  - `.*` Match the whole line
- `)*` Close the group and repeat 0+ times to optionally match all the following lines
- `$` End of string.

[Regex demo no match](https://regex101.com/r/dSaYya/1) | [Regex demo match](https://regex101.com/r/ckXx3i/1)

Comment: This addresses the requirements exactly, many thanks for your solution.

Comment: A note for anyone who uses or adapts this answer, ensure that you don't combine it with the 'm' flag since that would still allow invalid strings to validate if they are correct on at least one line.

Answer (score 2):

*As per my comment*: If you could *negate* the logic and react to **not** matching a **bad pattern** (`!badPattern.test(str)`), the whole thing becomes a lot easier.

For example:

```js
const cases = [
// good
`one|One
two|Two
three|Three`,

// good
`one|One
two|T,wo
three|Three`,

// bad
`one|One
two,|Two
three|Three`,
];

const badPattern = /,.*\|/;

const out = cases.map(val => ({
    input: val,
    result: !badPattern.test(val) ? 'good' : 'bad',
}))

console.log(out);
```